# Trying to get filtered values using laravel but isn't working properly, wrong result

Tags: laravel-5.5

I have `users` table and `subscriptions` table.

`subscriptions` table it has a foreign key column `user_id` and other column `status` of type enum and has set of values `('canceled','active','skipped','unpaid','pastdue','expired')`

In model, I defined their relation like,

```
public function subscription()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Subscription::class);
}
```

Now I am implementing a filter functionality

in this function in my dataTable class

```
public function query(User $model)
{
    if ($this->_filters['subscription_status']) {
        $status = $this->_filters['subscription_status'];

        $model = $model->whereHas('subscription', function($query) use ($status) {
            $query->where('status', $status);
        });
    }
```

Now when I tried to get the list of user  with subscription status `canceled`

the result, I got a list of users with status `active` and `cancelled` why the code above doesn't work?

Comment: The result you get, User status of active and cancelled or subscription status ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `with` not `has`. You can see the different.

> get the list of users **with** subscription status **canceled**

```
$model = $model->with(['subscription' => function ($query) use ($status) {
    $query->where('status', status);
}])
```

> get the list of users **has** subscription status **canceled**

```
$model = $model->whereHas('subscription', function($query) use ($status) {
    $query->where('status', $status);
});
```